American Airlines includes a free check-in bag in transconstinental flights. Is this the same in codeshare flights on a single ticket?
I'm buying a LHR -> JFK -> EZE ticket with American Airlines. The first part of the trip, LHR -> JFK, is done in a flight operated by British Airways.
If the entire flight were operated by American Airlines then I would have a free checked bag (source). However, I'm finding it hard to find if this is the case if I include a BA flight in the ticket (that I'm buying through the AA website).
Does anybody know if this is the case?

Please always also add the names of the airports or the cities as a single letter error (in writing or reading) gives a different airport often in a different country.

I do not see (in your link) that baggage to BUE are free, but on bottom there is links about having part of travel shared with BA

Did you actually mean intercontinental / transatlantic? Can you tell us which of the many rules on the linked page you refer to? Note also that there is no free checked bag for Basic Economy tickets even on "real" AA transatlantic flights.

Which airports? Your change of coded destination makes even more clear names should be given next to codes.

Unless you are getting the free bag through status:

If you are flying Basic Economy, you don't have a free checked bag included, whether the flight is BA or AA.

If you are flying in other Economy fare classes, then you do have a free checked bag included, whether the flight is BA or AA.


AA (from the page you linked to):

First checked bag is free for:

Eligible AAdvantage® Aviator® and Citi® / AAdvantage® cardmembers (on domestic American Airlines operated itineraries)
AAdvantage Gold® status
GOL Diamond Smiles members
oneworld® Ruby

or when traveling to these destinations*:

Argentina
Australia
Brazil
Chile
China
Colombia
Cuba
Ecuador
Haiti
Hong Kong
India
Israel
Japan
New Zealand
Panama
Paraguay
Peru
Qatar
South Korea
Transatlantic
Uruguay

*Excluding Basic Economy

(emphasis mine)
BA source:




Cabin
Checked bags




Economy Basic (cabin and hand bag only)
0


Economy (with checked bag)
1 (23kg) bag


Premium economy
2 (23kg) bags


Business
2 (32kg) bags


First
3 (32kg) bags



Gold and Silver Executive Club members, and oneworld Emerald and Sapphire members, may be entitled to more checked baggage.

(emphasis mine as well)
